# Why command `npm hardhat` doesn't create a new sample project?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, hardhat, create

I have installed hardhat, and I'm trying to create a sample project structure using `npm hardhat`. But it just shows me basic commands of hardhat as follows:

```
Hardhat version 2.9.1

Usage: hardhat [GLOBAL OPTIONS] <TASK> [TASK OPTIONS]

GLOBAL OPTIONS:

  --config              A Hardhat config file.
  --emoji               Use emoji in messages.
  --help                Shows this message, or a task's help if its name is provided
  --max-memory          The maximum amount of memory that Hardhat can use.      
  --network             The network to connect to.
  --show-stack-traces   Show stack traces.
  --tsconfig            A TypeScript config file.
  --verbose             Enables Hardhat verbose logging
  --version             Shows hardhat's version.


AVAILABLE TASKS:

  accounts      Prints the list of accounts
  check         Check whatever you need
  clean         Clears the cache and deletes all artifacts
  compile       Compiles the entire project, building all artifacts
  console       Opens a hardhat console
  flatten       Flattens and prints contracts and their dependencies
  help          Prints this message
  node          Starts a JSON-RPC server on top of Hardhat Network
  run           Runs a user-defined script after compiling the project
  test          Runs mocha tests

To get help for a specific task run: npx hardhat help [task]
```

Comment: It works here with hardhat v2.9.1 and node v14 & v16. The command should be `npx hardhat`.

Answer (score 1):

You must to run

```
$ npx hardhat --verbose
```

you will get the location of a hardhat config file like this:

```
$ hardhat:core:config Loading Hardhat config from /home/lyon/hardhat.config.js +0ms
```

delete it and run `npx hardhat` again

Answer (score 0):

its not `npm hardhat`, its `npx hardhat`.
ref: https://hardhat.org/getting-started/